# Creating a app.config file

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string, app-config, system.configuration

I have put together this code and was wondering how to call certain data from a .config or .ini file. I have looked into AppSettings and ConfigurationManager but it’s just too much for the noob brain to compute :-)

I have added the system.configuration reference class to the references class list.
Basically I want the variables for the MySQL stored on an external file that can be changed by an end user at a later time. I Could not put the whole code because it said I have exceeded 3000 lines or something.

```
DBServer = RemoteServer

dataBase = myDatabase

user = root

password = [the password here]
```

I have tried the following code with **app.config** but still nothing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="constring" connectionString="server=localhost; database=SchoolDB; user     id=root; password=Pa55w0rd;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Replaced the following in the **Mainwindow.cs**

```
string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=Pa55w0rd";
```

with this

```
string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
```

Then I get this error

***"Object reference not set to an instance of an Object"***

Ok so here is the **Mainwindow.cs**

```
public partial class Portal : Form
{      
    public Portal(string UserName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lbl_username.Text = UserName;
        timer1.Start();
        txt_staff_password1.PasswordChar = '*';
        load_loan_laptops();            
    }
    DataTable dbdataset;

    void load_loan_laptops()
    {
        //string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;    password=Pa55w0rd";
        string constring =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString;
        string Query = "Select * from schooldb.loans where Avail = 'yes';";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string devices = myReader.GetString("Device_Name");
                cmb_acer_loan.Items.Add(devices);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        conDataBase.Close();
    }
```

Please can someone help with this issue.

Comment: Hi Guys, Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

**problem :** Your `app.config` file has  `<connectionString>` tag instead of `<connectionStrings>`  tag.

**Solution:**  Replace `<connectionString>` with `<connectionStrings>`  and `</connectionString>` with `</connectionStrings>` in `app.config` file

Try This:

**app.config**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="constring" connectionString="datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=Pa55w0rd"/>
      </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**code:**

```
string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Sorry mate. Still nothing.

Comment: @user3051236 : what is the error message , please give me exact error message and where you are getting the error.

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an Object" is the error I get. Thanks

Comment: There is a login form that calls the Mainwindow.cs. When the Mainwindow opens it should load a MySQL table into the combobox. If I use the hard code it will open the Mainwindow but with the .config file it gives the error. Cheers

Comment: @user3051236: put same `connection string` which you used manually into `app.config` file and try, see `app.config` file in my edited my answer.